# Issue with drop down menu on my wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm totally Noob and New with programming. I know few thing like where to find CSS, rewriting PhP and stuff like that but it's very limited.

So actually, there is my question :

On my website (Woocommerce on Wordpress), I've got a drop down menu. When you reach the Home page, the drop down work perfectly.

But if you click on one the menu items like "Fleting and Spinning" section, you will see that you can't choose any of the items in the drop down menu because this one will disappear before the mouse cursor can get on to it.

Did someone know where and which CSS (I guess it's gonna be a class or something like that) do I have to modified to get things right ?

WEBSITE : [Wordpress Website](http://www.itsy-bitsy.ca/)

Hope I'm at the right place to seek for an answer ^^

Take care...

Comment: A response to "unclear what you're asking" : The actual linked page (the site's home page) did not have the issue described so it seemed unclear, however if you navigated to any of the sub pages, they did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on lines 3842 - 3846 of `/wordpress/wp-content/themes/theretailer/style.css`

Change :

```
.category_header
{
      padding: 63px 0;
      margin-top: -70px;
}
```

To :

```
.category_header
{
      padding: 0 0 63px 0 ;
      margin-top: -7px;
}
```

**IMPORTANT** If this is not a theme you created, you should not make changes directly to it.  You should instead create a child theme and make the changes there.

Comment: Work like charm, Thank you so much ^^